# Need MySQL Query ManyToMany Mapping Count Records

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many

i have **3 tables** (ManyToMany):

- movie
- moviegenre
- genre

Structure of my tables:

**movie:**

- id
- name
  ...

**genre:**

- id
- name

**moviegenre:**

- idMovie
- idGenre

Movie is connected with genre via the moviegenre table (ManyToMany connection).
Now id like to know how many movies i have for genre (for example "Action")

```
Example result:<br/>
Action  | 12<br/>
Horror  | 9<br/>
Thriller| 3<br/>
...
```

Could you please help me creating this "simple" query? (MySQL 5.5.13)

Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT G.name, count(MG.idMovie)
FROM MovieGenre MG
INNER JOIN Genre G on MG.idGenre = G.ID
GROUP BY G.name
```